# Mailchimp, Laravel curl_close() error

Tags: php, laravel-4

After following the mailchimp tut https://laracasts.com/lessons/bulk-email-notifications-part-2 and encountering the same error Jeff does within the video and making the same changes he does, i still get
curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
Anyone else have this, i'm using Homestead too as my environment.

Comment: Make sure a curl_init() call was made within scope. You haven't posted any code so that's the most I can offer.

Comment: Its hard to post code really there's quite a bit of it, maybe if you give the link a watch you will see what i'm meaning.

Comment: I'm guessing its to do with the .env.php file i have the API key stored in has doing dd($api_key) from the Mailchimp.php file returns boolean false;

Comment: Inside the Mailchimp.php theres this code which shows the curl_init() so it must be my ENV. http://laravel.io/bin/YOwBr